# force property as is always undefined

Tags: javascript

I want a property that would always be undefined:

```
var foo = {bar:undefined}
```

If someone later try to change property bar then also it should results in undefined.

```
foo.bar = 'someValue'//
foo.bar//this time this should result in undefined.
```

I mean how to set a property that is unchangeable.

Comment: You could create a setter that refuses to ever change the value of the property.  Or you could create a getter that always returns undefined.  Or, you can create the property with an initial value to not be writable using `Object.defineProperty()`.

Comment: The simplest you can do is `var foo = {}; Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {});`. That's all you need, since all other property descriptors (`enumerable`, etc.) are false by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, based on the hint from @somethinghere (who is breaking his/her own answer again…) here is a working example, that sets up an object member, which defaults to `undefined` and is not writeable:

```
var foo = {}
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false
});

foo.bar = 'abcdefg';

console.log( foo.bar ); // returns undefined
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Be aware that you may still remove and re-set this property. (While you can't simply overwrite it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can currently do this:

```
var foo = {}
Object.defineProperty(foo, 'bar', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: undefined
});
```

As some have pointed out, `undefined` would not equal `"undefined"`, one obviously being a string. However, I have added it for the sake of clarity as omitting the `value` property really loses the point of being able to use defineProperty to make them non-configurable. Once configured, its over, so its useful to have the value. Omit `value` if you want it to return `undefined`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: I tried this code.  It does not run as you have it for what appears like several reasons.

Comment: @feeela I amended it as well, I was just testing it and found out there were some errors.

Comment: @feeela Probably but it wouldn't return anything. Also, this makes it more obvious how you use the `defineProperty` function. I am aware that undefined does not equal undefined, but again, this is to make it easier to read.

Comment: @feela - You're telling me to read the doc?  I'm just telling the person who provided the answer that the code didn't work as posted.  I know how Object.defineProperty works myself, but this answer as originally posted was simply wrong so I pointed that out so the person who posted it could fix their answer.

Comment: @feeela You are right, sorry. Anyway better to omit `value` all together as redundant.

Comment: @somethinghere - if you want, you can use `value: undefined` or I guess leave out the `value` argument, but `value: 'undefined'` is simply wrong because that's a string value.  I'd really suggest you test your code because you've now had several wrong versions of this answer.

Comment: Waw people are bitey today. Mondays I guess. Anyways, the answer works, the documentation is there, its up to the gods now.